# Does Google Cloud SQL keeps connection open?

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am using Google Cloud SQL with App Engine and JDBC, and wonder about performance of stored procedures. MySQL compiles stored proc when client connects. When connection closes and opens again stored proc is reinitialized, which takes time. So I am wondering if GCP SQL behaves the same way and if it does for how long the client stays connected?

Comment: User defined functions are not supported: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/features#differences

Comment: I know that. My question was about stored proc performance